# A better way to prevent someone who is proxying/mirroring my site from requesting resources?

Tags: apache-2.4, mirroring

I serve a few static files and a WordPress blog on my DigitalOcean VPS and use dyn.com for DNS resolution. I've noticed lines like this in my Apache (2.4) access logs:

`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [20/Jul/2016:22:09:20 +0000] "GET /blog/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.5.3 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://unfamiliardomainname.com/blog/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"`

Turns out `unfamiliardomainname.com` is mirroring my site but requesting files from my server any time someone goes to it (is there a name for this specific phenomenon?). After filtering out all the unique IPs in these lines, I notice they all point to Incapsula. Sure enough, when I stop Apache and try to go to `unfamiliardomainname.com/blog`, I get an Incapsula error page.

I'm going to be charitable and assume that whoever owns `unfamiliardomainname.com` may have had my IP address before I did and never removed this IP address from their Incapsula account (I'm not sure if that's how it works with Incapsula, so feel free to let me know if that's even possible). I've already reported this to Incapsula and blocked the offending IPs with `iptables`, but beyond that is there anything I can do to prevent something like this from happening again? I use `fail2ban`, I was thinking of setting up a filter. If one already exists, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Disclaimer: My unethical opinion only.  When someone does this, I love it.  I can change the content on their site to anything I want using rewrite rules.  They are doing this at their own perril.  If it were me, I would rewrite the requests to add tacky mildly offensive animations to their site.  Have fun!

Comment: @Aaron I tried doing this both in the main Apache conf file and in .htaccess, but neither worked. Can confirm mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: For the requests that include a referer of another domain, this can totally be done.  If requests are being proxied, you would have to rewrite based on the `REMOTE_ADDR`.  Hopefully all the requests are from unique IP addresses, because if you are seeing multiple user-agents with the same IP, they could be doing MITM attacks to gather WP logins.

Answer (score 0):

You need an hotlink protection, you can do that with Apache mod_rewrite here an example with the hotlink protection for the images:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-mod_rewrite-hot-linking-images-leeching-howto/

Maybe there is also a plug-in for Wordpress that can prevent this but I didn't checked.

Comment: Thanks. Tried this, none of my mod_rewrite rules seemed to work. It's enabled, though. Not sure what the problem might be.